# Cannot retrieve information after sorting selectable form

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am generating a form with this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" id="priority" action="{{ url('/somewhere') }}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    @foreach($items as $item)
        <li class="list-group-item active">
            {{$item->name}}
            <input type="hidden" name="priority[]" value="{{$item->id}}">
        </li>
    @endforeach
</form>
<button form="priority" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I made this list selectable using [jQuery sortable lists](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) but after changing the position of the options the `priority[]` does not exist. When I check the form after changing positions, the inputs and the list elements change as intended. Also if I submit the list without chaning anything at all, the `priority[]` array is actually filled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: @charlietfl This post follow every single guideline.

Comment: @prgrm it looks ok-ish, just requires an actual example: **this** code works, **that** code doesn't, **these** lines were changed - and kept to minimum. Based on the current question it's hard to say what "position changing" is necessary to reproduce whatever the error.

Comment: Probably after manipulation with jQuery sortable, your inputs are going out from form. So Just ensure your elements are falling back to correct DOM level.

Comment: @prgrm no it doesn't...there is no way for any of us to reproduce your issue based only on what is shown. How difficult is it to create a demo and show us?